# Books for combinatorial thinking

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

I have looked through many discrete mathematics books but they don't put much emphasis on combinatorial thinking.What books could you recommend that are more problem-oriented and emphasize combinatorial thinking?

Comment: I am making this reference request into a Community Wiki

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might want to check these out (there are a coupe of others, but I am not home and the titles are escaping me).

- Proofs that Really Count: The Art of Combinatorial Proof (Dolciani Mathematical Expositions)
- Principles and Techniques in Combinatori, Chen Chuan-Chong, Koh Khee-Meng
- Applied Combinatorics, Alan Tucker
- You might want to look at [*Donald E. Knuth - The Art of Computer Programming -  Volume 4, Combinatorial Algorithms -  Volume 4A, Combinatorial Algorithms: Part 1*](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/)

I'd also recommend books on problem solving, for example:

- 102 Combinatorial Problems, Titu Andreescu, Zuming Feng
- Combinatorial Problems in Mathematical Competitions (Mathematical Olympiad), Yao Zhang
- Combinatorial Problems and Exercises, Laszlo Lovasz

Regards

Comment: This needs  multiple pluses.

Comment: Nice references...I also line Peter Cameron's text on Combinatorics, and his site for it, too (see Babak's profile with a great "tribute" to him)! +1

Answer (score 3):

[Concrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025) has a feast of lip-smacking mathematics in it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at [Proofs that really count](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883853337)

Answer (score 1):

H.J.Ryser, Combinatorial Mathematics

M.Hall, Combinatorial Theory

Answer (score 1):

I am working on James A Anderson's book called Discrete Mathematics with combinatorics and I'm pretty happy with it. I like the combinatorial part of mathematics the most and this book does try to look at things from that point of view on many cases. Although you should really pick it up at a library and look for yourself.

It is not however very problem oriented. You can try concrete mathematics by Knuth, Graham and Patashnik. Also, I find the problems on Van Lint and R.M WIlson's book really good (those are just in combinatorics though).

Answer (score 1):

The freely available for download [*Combinatorics Through Guided Discovery*](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/news-resources/electronic/kpbogart/) by Kenneth Bogart is a problem-based introduction to combinatorics.  I think it is a great resource for someone who is starting out in combinatorics through self-study.